# Unable to write to file output.txt

Tags: c++, file-io, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to write a program. The first file will be opened for input and the second file will be opened for output. (It will be assumed that the first file contains sentences that end with a period.) The program will read the contents of the first file and change all the letters to lowercase except the first letter of each sentence, which should be made uppercase. The revised contents should be stored in the second file.

I've been able to get my code to work in that I successfully converted the contents in input.txt to the above requirements (all sentences are lowercase except for the first word in each sentence). However, this content does not appear in `output.txt`

Both `input.txt` and `output.txt` are in the same directory next to `main.cpp`.

I tried using different IDEs but that didn't do anything. I also tried moving around the location of output.txt but that did nothing also.

> SAMPLE INPUT: google's homepage includes a button labeled "I'm Feeling
>   Lucky".  When a user types in a search AND clicks on the button the
>   user will be taken directly to the first search result, bypassing the
>   search engine results page.
>
> SAMPLE OUTPUT: Google's homepage includes a button labeled "i'm
>   feeling lucky".  When a user types in a search and clicks on the
>   button the user will be taken directly to the first search result,
>   bypassing the search engine results page.

```
    string inFileName, outFileName;
    string line;
    char c;

    cout << "Enter input file name: ";
    cin >> inFileName;


    fstream fin, fout;
    fin.open(inFileName.c_str(), ios::in);
    fout.open(outFileName.c_str(), ios::out);


    if (fin.fail())
    {
        cout << "INPUT FILE DOES NOT EXIST (DNE)\n";
        system("pause");

        return 1;

    }
```

Nothing shows up in `output.txt` (it's blank). From what I've noticed this command `fout << line << "." << endl;` isn't doing anything.

[Here's another screenshot]that shows what's in my terminal as well as what is in `input.txt` and `output.txt`:

You'll notice that in the terminal the proper conversion is shown but I am unable to get that text in the terminal into `output.txt`.

Comment: _"Code works ...."_ It doesn't ...

Comment: _"Both input.txt and output.txt are in the same directory next to main.cpp."_ Never mind where main.cpp is - what's the current working directory when you run the program?

Comment: Pleased provide a [mcve]. I should be able to copy, paste and compile the code. Try hardcoded variable names.

Comment: It looks okay. As far as I can see, there is nothing wrong. Can you add sample input and output?

Comment: I added a sample input/output.

Comment: Hmm. To be clear, `cout << line << "." << endl;` shows what's expected, but `fout << line << "." << endl;` doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: I meant hardcoded filenames like `outFileName = "output.txt"` instead of reading them from user. Reduce your code to a minimum. Remove user input.

Comment: I have to let it be read from the user (its what the assignment requires)

Comment: @Chipster yes that's exactly what I mean. fout << line<< "." doesn't seem to write the contents of 'line' into output.txt

Comment: I think the idea here is to remove variables for debugging purposes. Hardcoding the names will help with that.

Comment: After you fixed your problem you can add user input

Comment: @ThomasSablik The problem is that I can't write to output.txt. I tried hardcoding it before but it still doesn't seem to work. I added a screenshot of where my files are located with respect to main.cpp. Do you think the problem has to do with file location?

Comment: If the code runs without errors and warnings and the output file is empty, then the code is not entering in the while loop. Maybe the input is empty?

Comment: You keep insisting in checking the location of the files with respect to main.cpp, but that is useless, you need to check the files with respect to the compiled code.

Comment: The input isn't empty. I verified that by the command: cout << line << endl; It's reading input.txt and performing the conversion. All that is going wrong is taking that updated conversion and writing to output.txt. Also in the terminal window I made sure I printed the conversion. here's a screenshot of my problem in a nutshell (https://imgur.com/a/6BqEcUp)

Comment: @myradio How would I check the files with respect to my compiled code?

Comment: @Dwight Find where the `.exe` file is. It's probably somewhere in the `Debug` folder.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I checked my Debug folder but there are no .exe files. There are files labeled .pdb, .obj, and .ilk

Comment: How are you running your code? The executable is the code you are running. If using an IDE, try to see where is the output directory of the compiler.

Comment: Did you try absolute paths. Relative paths are relative to your current working directory.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After every source code is compiled, a executable program is created. On Windows, it has `.exe` extension. The program should have the same name from your source code.

Try to find where it is created. It can be inside the `temp` folder or maybe where `Visual Studio` is installed.

Your text document (`.txt`) file for storing output has to be in the same directory with the executable.

I executed your program on my device (on *Code::Blocks IDE* though). It went as it should.

[image]

Comment: I looked through my directory but still couldn't find any .exe extensions. I'm using Visual Studio 2017. Here's a screenshot of how things look on my end: https://imgur.com/a/Q65GC6F

Comment: The second file from the top maybe? Place your output text document inside the `Debug` folder and re-run the program.

Comment: What is the extension for the second file in the screenshot? The system says it's type is *Application", so it should be a executable file (`.exe`).

Comment: you are right @Meraj al Maksud that is an .exe file. However when I put output.txt in the same directory it still doesn't do anything

Comment: The current setup I have is that input.txt is in the same directory as main.cpp and output.txt is in Debug, in the same directory as the .exe file. However, nothing has changed, output.txt remains empty

Comment: Does it work? I think it should because the program was already successfully taking input from the input text file in the first place. All you needed to do is to put the output file along with the `.exe`.

Comment: oh, wait lol did it work for you Meraj al Maksud? You used Code::Block IDE, right? Where did you end up storing input.txt and output.txt?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197425/discussion-between-meraj-al-maksud-and-dwight).

Comment: It doesn't work I put output.txt in the same disrectory as the .exe file and nothing changed. I put input.txt next to the main.cpp file, that's how it should be, right?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all the above answers and they are appropriate for all the users. In my case though there was a segmentation fault that led to file write failure. Try rectifying any segmentation faults.